# AWS Systems Manager using cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-ssm

I started writing something for AWS Systems Manager to:

1. Create custom Windows and Linux images and
2. How to apply Windows and Linux Updates to the AMIs that would be useful...

I'm following [this example](https://github.com/miztiik/AWS-Demos/tree/master/How-To/setup-ami-lifecycle-management-using-ssm/build-scripts), but am not able to get results when I run it.

This is the error I receive:

> Template format error: At least one Resources member must be defined.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here, I have gone through the code but not able to find what I am doing wrong.

```
#description: Create a Golden AMI with Linux distribution packages(ClamAV) and Amazon
#software(SSM & Inspector). For details,see https://github.com/miztiik/AWS-Demos/tree/master/How-To/setup-ami-lifecycle-management-using-ssm
Resources:
 Ec2Instance:
   Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'  
assumeRole: "{{AutomationAssumeRole}}"
parameters:
  SourceAmiId:
    type: String
    description: "(Required) The source Amazon Machine Image ID."
    default: ami-0d2692b6acea72ee6
  InstanceIamRole:
    type: String
    description: "(Required) The name of the role that enables Systems Manager (SSM)
      to manage the instance."
    default: ManagedInstanceRole
  AutomationAssumeRole:
    type: String
    description: "(Required) The ARN of the role that allows Automation to perform
      the actions on your behalf."
    default: arn:aws:iam::{{global:ACCOUNT_ID}}:role/AutomationServiceRole
  SubnetId:
    type: String
    description: "(Required) The subnet that the created instance will be placed into."
    default: subnet-0a72519be8028a56c
  TargetAmiName:
    type: String
    description: "(Optional) The name of the new AMI that will be created. Default
      is a system-generated string including the source AMI id, and the creation time
      and date."
    default: GoldenAMI-RH-7_on_{{global:DATE_TIME}}
  InstanceType:
    type: String
    description: "(Optional) Type of instance to launch as the workspace host. Instance
      types vary by region. Default is t2.micro."
    default: t2.micro
  PreUpdateScript:
    type: String
    description: (Optional) URL of a script to run before updates are applied. Default
      ("none") is to not run a script.
    default: none
  PostUpdateScript:
    type: String
    description: (Optional) URL of a script to run after package updates are applied.
      Default ("none") is to not run a script.
    default: none
  IncludePackages:
    type: String
    description: (Optional) Only update these named packages. By default ("all"),
      all available updates are applied.
    default: all
  ExcludePackages:
    type: String
    description: (Optional) Names of packages to hold back from updates, under all
      conditions. By default ("none"), no package is excluded.
    default: none
  lambdaFunctionName:
    type: String
    description: "(Required) The name of the lambda function. Default ('none') is
      to not run a script."
    default: Automation-UpdateSsmParam
mainSteps:
- name: launchInstance
  action: aws:runInstances
  maxAttempts: 5
  timeoutSeconds: 1200
  onFailure: Abort
  inputs:
    ImageId: "{{SourceAmiId}}"
    InstanceType: "{{InstanceType}}"
    SubnetId: "{{ SubnetId }}"
    UserData: 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
    MinInstanceCount: 1
    MaxInstanceCount: 3
    IamInstanceProfileName: "{{InstanceIamRole}}"
- name: updateOSSoftware
  action: aws:runCommand
  maxAttempts: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 3600
  onFailure: Abort
  inputs:
    DocumentName: AWS-RunShellScript
    InstanceIds:
    - "{{launchInstance.InstanceIds}}"
    Parameters:
      commands:
      - set -e
      - '[ -x "$(which wget)" ] && get_contents=''wget $1 -O -'''
      - '[ -x "$(which curl)" ] && get_contents=''curl -s -f $1'''
      - eval $get_contents https://aws-ssm-downloads-{{global:REGION}}.s3.amazonaws.com/scripts/aws-update-linux-instance
        > /tmp/aws-update-linux-instance
      - chmod +x /tmp/aws-update-linux-instance
      - "/tmp/aws-update-linux-instance --pre-update-script '{{PreUpdateScript}}'
        --post-update-script '{{PostUpdateScript}}' --include-packages '{{IncludePackages}}'
        --exclude-packages '{{ExcludePackages}}' 2>&1 | tee /tmp/aws-update-linux-instance.log"
- name: installCustomizations
  action: aws:runCommand
  maxAttempts: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 600
  onFailure: Abort
  inputs:
    DocumentName: AWS-RunShellScript
    InstanceIds:
    - "{{launchInstance.InstanceIds}}"
    Parameters:
      commands:
      - curl -O http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
      - rpm -ivh epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
      - yum -y install httpd
      - systemctl enable httpd
      - systemctl restart httpd
      - sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install -y clamav
      - yum-config-manager --disable epel
      - cat /etc/motd >> /var/www/html/index.html
      - echo 'Welcome' >> /var/www/html/index.html
      - cat > /etc/motd <<- EOF
      - "           __  __ _                 _                        _   _             "
      - "     /\\   |  \\/  (_)     /\\        | |                      | | (_)            "
      - "    /  \\  | \\  / |_     /  \\  _   _| |_ ___  _ __ ___   __ _| |_ _  ___
        \ _ __  "
      - "   / /\\ \\ | |\\/| | |   / /\\ \\| | | | __/ _ \\| '_ ` _ \\ / _` | __|
        |/ _ \\| '_ \\ "
      - "  / ____ \\| |  | | |  / ____ \\ |_| | || (_) | | | | | | (_| | |_| | (_)
        | | | |"
      - " /_/    \\_\\_|  |_|_| /_/    \\_\\__,_|\\__\\___/|_| |_| |_|\\__,_|\\__|_|\\___/|_|
        |_|"
      - "   "
      - "   "
      - EOF
- name: installInspectorAgent
  action: aws:runCommand
  maxAttempts: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 600
  onFailure: Abort
  inputs:
    DocumentName: AmazonInspector-ManageAWSAgent
    InstanceIds:
    - "{{launchInstance.InstanceIds}}"
    Parameters:
      Operation: Install
- name: installUnifiedCloudWatchAgent
  action: aws:runCommand
  maxAttempts: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 600
  onFailure: Abort
  inputs:
    DocumentName: AWS-ConfigureAWSPackage
    InstanceIds:
    - "{{launchInstance.InstanceIds}}"
    Parameters:
      name: AmazonCloudWatchAgent
      action: Install
- name: stopInstance
  action: aws:changeInstanceState
  maxAttempts: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 1200
  onFailure: Abort
  inputs:
    InstanceIds:
    - "{{launchInstance.InstanceIds}}"
    DesiredState: stopped
- name: createImage
  action: aws:createImage
  maxAttempts: 3
  onFailure: Abort
  inputs:
    InstanceId: "{{launchInstance.InstanceIds}}"
    ImageName: "{{TargetAmiName}}"
    NoReboot: true
    ImageDescription: AMI Generated by EC2 Automation on {{global:DATE_TIME}} from
      {{SourceAmiId}}
- name: createEncryptedCopy
  action: aws:copyImage
  maxAttempts: 3
  onFailure: Abort
  inputs:
    SourceImageId: "{{createImage.ImageId}}"
    SourceRegion: "{{global:REGION}}"
    ImageName: Encrypted-{{TargetAmiName}}
    ImageDescription: Encrypted GoldenAMI by SSM Automation on {{global:DATE_TIME}}
      from source AMI {{createImage.ImageId}}
    Encrypted: true
- name: createTagsForEncryptedImage
  action: aws:createTags
  maxAttempts: 1
  onFailure: Continue
  inputs:
    ResourceType: EC2
    ResourceIds:
    - "{{createEncryptedCopy.ImageId}}"
    Tags:
    - Key: Automation-Id
      Value: "{{automation:EXECUTION_ID}}"
    - Key: Owner
      Value: Mystique
    - Key: SourceAMI
      Value: "{{SourceAmiId}}"
    - Key: Amazon-Inspector
      Value: 'true'
    - Key: Amazon-SSM
      Value: 'true'
    - Key: Encrypted
      Value: 'true'
- name: updateSsmParam
  action: aws:invokeLambdaFunction
  timeoutSeconds: 1200
  maxAttempts: 1
  onFailure: Abort
  inputs:
    FunctionName: Automation-UpdateSsmParam
    Payload: '{"parameterName":"/GoldenAMI/Linux/RedHat-7/latest", "parameterValue":"{{createEncryptedCopy.ImageId}}"}'
- name: terminateInstance
  action: aws:changeInstanceState
  maxAttempts: 3
  onFailure: Continue
  inputs:
    InstanceIds:
    - "{{launchInstance.InstanceIds}}"
    DesiredState: terminated
- name: deleteUnEcryptedImage
  action: aws:deleteImage
  maxAttempts: 3
  timeoutSeconds: 180
  onFailure: Abort
  inputs:
    ImageId: "{{createImage.ImageId}}"
outputs:
- createImage.ImageId
```

I expect it to run and create a parameter store and a document inside AWS SSM.

Comment: Do you try to execute the code you've posted as a CloudFormation template?

Comment: after defining resources, it throwing Invalid templete property Outputs, assumerole, parameters, mainsteps.

Comment: @lexicore, yes i tried to execute.. then i m getting these errors. don't know what wrong here. i m newbie in cloudformation..

Comment: Because this does not really look like a CloudFormation template at all. Start here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/sample-templates-services-eu-central-1.html

Comment: Hi i have created template in yaml format but now i am getting error :- 
invalid template property or properties [outputs, assumeRole, parameters, mainSteps] 

@lexicore

Comment: @lexicore i pasted new yaml file in above question

Comment: This still does not look like CloudFormation. Start here: https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/getting-started/?nc1=h_ls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you pasted above is a [Systems Manager (SSM) document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-automation.html) rather than a CloudFormation template. That's why CF complains Template format error.

Similar to CloudFormation template, the SSM Document supports both JSON and YAML formats.

As you can see from the [README description](https://github.com/miztiik/AWS-Demos/tree/master/How-To/setup-ami-lifecycle-management-using-ssm#create-custom-automation-document) in that same GitHub repository, the JSON file is used to create a SSM Document.